# How to use multiple actions in a single route in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two forms in different components. And I'm showing the result in whole another component. I'm using `<Form>` from `react-router-dom`. And getting the data using `action`. It works fine if I have one action. So I tried adding an extra `action`, something like,

```
{
  path: '/show-result`,
  element: <ShowResult />,
  action: actionFromFirstComponent,
  action: actionFromSecondComponent
}
```

It didn't work as expected. I also tried `action: [actionFromFirstComponent, actionFromSecondComponent]`. But `react-router-dom` throws me `handler is not a function` error.

I tried searching **multiple action in react router route** in google. But, it only shows how to set multiple routes for one component.

Comment: I suppose you could use an anonymous function that calls both those actions?

Comment: @geisterfurz007, can you write down the code so that I can fully understand what you're trying to say

Comment: You can have only a single action. The single action should take additional data so it can conditionally apply one action logic or another.

Answer (score 9):

You can have only a single action. The single action should take additional data so it can conditionally apply one action logic or another. One way to do this is to append a hidden id field that will be submitted with the `formData` when the form is submitted. The action should read this field value and conditionally apply the correct action logic.

Example:

```
const multiFormAction = async (actionArg) => {
  const formData = await actionArg.request.formData();
  const formId = formData.get("form-id");

  switch (formId) {
    case "form 1":
      // This is form 1 logic
      return actionFromFirstComponent(actionArg); // <-- pass action arg through

    case "form 2":
      // This is form 2 logic
      return actionFromSecondComponent(actionArg); // <-- pass action arg through

    default:
      // Form was submitted without an id
      // What to do... throw or return error? Ignore? You decide.
  }
};
```

```
{
  path: '/show-result`,
  element: <ShowResult />,
  action: multiFormAction,
}
```

```
...

<Form method="post">
  <input name="form-id" hidden defaultValue="form 1" />
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</Form>

...

<Form method="post">
  <input name="form-id" hidden defaultValue="form 2" />
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</Form>

...
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-multiple-actions-in-a-single-route-in-react-router-dom]

Comment: I am curious to know what will happen, when the two form component has their own routes and their own action as well. ex - /page1 -> has form1 and /page2 -> has form 2 and routes page1 and page2 has their own actions. Do you know?

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma If two different routes each have their own "instance" of a loader/action and each render their own UI that contains a form, then each is used individually. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: well explained, thanks for sharing the answer

Answer (score 1):

### Well you can make use of name and value on your button and use those to differentiate while you submit.

```
    async function action({ request }) {
  let formData = await request.formData();
  let intent = formData.get("intent");

  if (intent === "edit") {
    await editSong(formData);
    return { ok: true };
  }

  if (intent === "add") {
    await addSong(formData);
    return { ok: true };
  }

  throw json(
    { message: "Invalid intent" },
    { status: 400 }
  );
}

function Component() {
  let song = useLoaderData();

  // When the song exists, show an edit form
  if (song) {
    return (
      <Form method="post">
        <p>Edit song lyrics:</p>
        {/* Edit song inputs */}
        <button type="submit" name="intent" value="edit">
          Edit
        </button>
      </Form>
    );
  }

  // Otherwise show a form to add a new song
  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <p>Add new lyrics:</p>
      {/* Add song inputs */}
      <button type="submit" name="intent" value="add">
        Add
      </button>
    </Form>
  );
```